# Unable to append data to string using serializeArray() and array.push()

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, serialization

After following answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289349/jquery-appending-to-serialize), I'm trying to append data to a string using:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='a' />A
<input type='checkbox' name='b' checked='checked'/>B
<input type='checkbox' name='c' />C

var attr_str = $('input').serializeArray();
attr_str.push({q:'hello',p:'world'});
```

But it returns `[object Object],[object Object]`. What am I missing?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ECahX/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but only the input which is checked is going to be included by `serializeArray()`. You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

But your array is being returned as an object as it should. To see the layout of the JSON of this object you could try `JSON.stringify(attr_str)`.

```
var attr_str = $('input').serializeArray();

attr_str.push({q:'hello',p:'world'});

$('body').append('<br><br>string='+JSON.stringify(attr_str));
```

This will show that you are appending an object into your`attr_str` array but only input 'b' is included because it is the only one that is checked. `string=[{"name":"b","value":"on"}{"q":"hello","p":"world"}]`
To access this object you would simply use `attr_str[0]` then for a property of that object use `attr_str[0].name`. Which would print `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The `serializeArray` returns an array of objects, each contains the properties `name` and `value`.

Ex

```
[{"name": "x", "value": "y"}, {"name": "a", "value": "b"}, ...]
```

That is why it is printing `[Object, Object]`.

You can use `JSON.stringify(attr_str)` to print the stringified values if you want. But `JSON.stringify` is not natively supported in old browsers, so you may have to include a compatibility library like [JOSN2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ECahX/5/).