# Display a partial view or hit controller action upon a check from an ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax call :

```
    $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("GetMatch", "Test")",
                    data: {
                        Name: $("[name='Name']").val(),
                        Surname: $("[name='Surname']").val(),
                        Email: $("[name='Email']").val(),
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data.length);
                        if (data.length <= 13){
                            SaveQuote();
                        } else {
                            alert("matche")
                            }
});
```

The GetMatch action in the controller is as below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetClientMatch(ClientBusinessModel contactPerson)
{
    *search for a list*
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/_Client.cshtml", list);
    } else
        return Json(new { data = contactPerson }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What I want to do is upon success, if the list is not empty, display the partial view _Client.cshtml.  This is ok.
But in case the the list is empty, call another action of the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CreateClient(SchoolModel school, ClientBusinessModel contactPerson, long QuotationId, long LeadId)
{
    *some aciotns*
}
```

The first thing is how do I test if the data returned, upon the ajax call to action GetClientMatch, is a partial View or the contactPerson?
Right now, I am doing the test on the length of the data.
And also how do I save the form data AND the contactPerson returned by the first ajax call?

My SaveQuote function:

```
function SaveQuote() {
        var obj = $('#frmSchool').serialize();
        var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
        $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "@Url.Action("CreateClient", "Test")",
                 data: obj + "
                            Name: $("[name='Name']").val(),
                            Surname: $("[name='Surname']").val(),
                            Email: $("[name='Email']").val(),
                 success: function (data) {
                     $('#ProductInformation').html(data);
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                     alert(error);
                 }
             });
    }
```

How can I hit the controller action with the form data and the contactPerson model when the list returned in the first ajax call is empty?

Comment: Hint: You need to use `serializeArray()` instead of `serialize()` to be able to push additional data. The pushed data can still be posted with same way as `serialize()` one.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto : How can I use serializeArray() for the form data and the model?

Comment: Simply use `var obj = $('#frmSchool').serializeArray();` and use series of `obj.push()` methods to append additional data. Then use `data` property in AJAX call like `data: obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `serialize()` to serialize the form, you need to use `serializeArray()` which enables pushing additional data before assigning to AJAX callback like the following example (see related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289349/jquery-appending-to-serialize)):

```
function SaveQuote() {
    var obj = $('#frmSchool').serializeArray();

    // pushing additional data to existing array
    obj.push({ name: "Name", value: $("[name='Name']").val() });
    obj.push({ name: "Surname", value: $("[name='Surname']").val() });
    obj.push({ name: "Email", value: $("[name='Surname']").val() });

    var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CreateClient", "Test")",
        data: obj,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ProductInformation').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Additionally, if you want to check if the response returns partial view or JSON response containing `contactPerson`, put an `if`-condition to check existence of specified object key:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetClientMatch(ClientBusinessModel contactPerson)
{
    // *search for a list*
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Partials/_Client.cshtml", list);
    } 
    else
    {
        // key name intentionally changed for disambiguation
        return Json(new { contact = contactPerson }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function SaveQuote() {
    var obj = $('#frmSchool').serializeArray();
    obj.push({ name: "Name", value: $("[name='Name']").val() });
    obj.push({ name: "Surname", value: $("[name='Surname']").val() });
    obj.push({ name: "Email", value: $("[name='Surname']").val() });

    var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("CreateClient", "Test")",
        data: obj,
        success: function (data) {
            // check if contact person exists
            if (data.contact == undefined) {
                // returns partial view
                $('#ProductInformation').html(data);
            }
            else {
                // call another action here, e.g. create client function
                createClient(data.contact, ...);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The method to call another action depends on action attribute set in that action (`GET`/`POST` method) and required parameters to pass with that action.